# A systemd script for s3ql remote FUSE mounting

Tags: systemd

I find systemd very exciting, but how would I use it to write a script to mount an [s3ql](http://code.google.com/p/s3ql/) filesystem? For example, the s3ql developer provides an [upstart config](http://code.google.com/p/s3ql/source/browse/contrib/s3ql_upstart.conf) that does the job.

Specifically, on startup mount.s3ql must be run (as the desired user as this is a FUSE filesystem), and on shutdown umount.s3ql must be run. In addition, what if we want to fsck.s3ql the filesystem before mounting, or run a Unison synchronization step after startup and before shutdown (all modifications I have made on my own personal upstart).

At first glance I would think I would want to setup a mount [unit](http://0pointer.de/public/systemd-man/systemd.mount.html) on systemd, but it appears that the service [unit](http://0pointer.de/public/systemd-man/systemd.service.html) actually fits better with pre and post exec startup commands. (All the man pages are available [here](http://0pointer.de/public/systemd-man/).)

And what .target do I depend on to encode the dependency on a network connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, it seems that for `mount.s3ql` and `umount.s3ql`, a generic `.mount` unit might be appropriate. Both the `mount` command and *systemd* support `mount.fstype` helpers when mounting. However, the helper must support the standard `-o options` method of passing options, which *s3ql* does not. Also, the same limitations apply [as with /etc/fstab](http://www.rath.org/s3ql-docs/mount.html).

So you might actually be better with a `.service` unit that calls the desired commands:

```
[Unit]
Wants=unison@s3ql.service
After=unison@s3ql.service

[Service]
Type=forking
Environment=AUTHFILE=/path/to/authinfo2
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mount.s3ql --authfile ${AUTHFILE} ${BUCKET} ${MOUNTPOINT}
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/umount.s3ql ${MOUNTPOINT}
TimeoutSec=5min
```

---

Since there is no standard way of configuring networks, much less one that actually checks whether the connection is actually working, there is no standard *systemd* target for what you want. There is `network.target`, though, but it might consider itself started when the connection is not available yet.

If you are using NetworkManager, your distribution might have included a unit that runs `nm-online` – for example, Arch calls it `NetworkManager-wait-online.service`.

```
[Unit]
Require=NetworkManager-wait-online.service
After=NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

Comment: `mount.s3ql` supports `-o options` (and always has). Recent versions also come with systemd notification support, so `Type=forking` is no longer correct.

Comment: Is there a working example for Ubuntu 20.04?